# Override virtual function with different function signature by using variadic functions

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I have a subclass called `createA`, which is the subclass of class `creator`. I want to override the function `create` by using different function signature in class `createA`. This is what I want to achieve.

```
//factory.h
class creator{
  virtual FactoryPtr create ()=0;
}

//createA.h
class createA: public creator{
    FactoryPtr create (string f, bool s, const Observation& obs, std::string dom,...etc) override;
}
```

The `...etc` means there are going to be other parameters in the function signature, but I think listing four parameters should be fine for an example.

I want to know is there anyway to achieve what I want by using variadic function or any other method? I don't have c++17, so the library `<any>` doesn't work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: To override functions their signatures must match exactly.

Comment: As  πάντα ῥεῖ and Taylor stated, you cannot override a virtual function with a function having a different signature.

Are you writing an object factory, which creates objects of a sub-class?  Factories should not need virtual functions, the base class of the objects it creates usually do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ has pretty strict rules about what virtual functions can and cant be. Among other things, your function types need to match up.

To understand why this is the case, lets think about arrays. In C++, if you have any array of creator classes, then how will you know what types to call on one index in your array vs another.

It you did not know, C++ is a compiled language with no runtime types. That means keywords like instanceof and typeof do not exist in C++.